# How to save a ggcoxzph plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cox-regression

I fitted a Cox model and then tested the proportionnal hazards assumption using `cox.zph`.

I plotted the scaled Schoenfeld residuals using `ggcoxzph` and the result is so neat I'd like to save it.

Since my variable is a factor, `ggcoxzph` returns a grid of 4 plots, with the Global pvalue on top.

```
> coxt %>% cox.zph %>% ggcoxzph %>% class
[1] "ggcoxzph" "ggsurv"   "list"
```

Problem is `ggsave()` doesn't accept those classes :

> no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('ggcoxzph', 'ggsurv', 'list')"

`coxt %>% cox.zph %>% ggcoxzph %>% print` works like a charm though.

Since this test is in a function (which will be applied to a list of variables), it would be better not to print the plot before saving it.

How can I save my plot this way ?

Comment: Have you tried `class(ggcoxzph) <-  c("gg",    "ggplot")` and then `ggsave`?

Comment: nice idea, but "Error in plot_clone(plot) : attempt to apply non-function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `gridExtra`

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
ggsave("ggcoxzph", arrangeGrob(grobs = object.ggcoxzph))
```

full example

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + ecog.ps + rx, data=ovarian)
cox.zph.fit <- cox.zph(fit)
plot_zph = ggcoxzph(cox.zph.fit)
library(gridExtra)
ggsave("ggcoxzph.pdf", arrangeGrob(grobs = plot_zph))
```